# Не записывает стили на breakpoints css

Tags: html, css, css3

Прошу помочь разобраться с несложной проблемой, с которой мне пришлось столкнуться.

Есть разметка:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="imagebox"></div>
</div>
```

И стиль для него, для примера такой :

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Мне нужно изменить размер на разных разрешениях, и так как я начинаю с десктопа то после основных стилей я решил воспользоваться медиазапросом, для некоторых разрешений:

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1279px) {
   .container {
        width: 750px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .container {
        width: 500px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .container {
        width: 250px;
    }
}
```

Но проблема возникает почему-то на последнем разрешении, которое от 0 до 767, на этом разрешении сохраняются стили которые записаны с 768 до 1023.

Пробовал @media (max-width: 767px), @media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px), @media only screen and (max-width: 767px), вообщем всё что удалось раскопать в интернете, но почему-то ничего не сработало.

Подскажите, возможно где-то есть явная ошибка, может запросы выставлены не в том порядке, или не в том месте?

Comment: Ошибки нет, должно работать. И работает: https://jsfiddle.net/36hykc02/, кстати. [mcve] давай.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="imagebox">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam placeat harum saepe, unde fugit consectetur. Ad eligendi quidem labore officia 
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

и CSS

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
    .imagebox {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 201px)  and (max-width: 400px) {
    .imagebox {
        background-color: orange;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px)  and (max-width: 600px) {
    .imagebox {
        background-color: green;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px)  and (max-width: 800px) {
    .imagebox {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 801px)  and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .imagebox {
        background-color: indigo ;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1001px)  and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .imagebox {
        background-color: violet ;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
    .imagebox {
        background-color: purple ;
    }
}
```

p.s.

Даже не посмотрел на твой код.
Он рабочий, только надо добавить meta тег -

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

чтобы в Хроме и других браузерах все норм отображалось.

Comment: И что за код? А этот мета-тег нужен только для мобильных браузеров, о которых в вопросе ничего не говорится.

Comment: Если открыть отладчик хрома и начать менять размер окна, то оно меняется как на мобильных экранах. И происходит то что он и говорит, медия от 0 до 767 игнорится. А с мета тегом все работает

Comment: А проверить сначала? Если ты эмуляцию мобилки не включаешь, а просто меняешь размер окна, то ничего такого не происходит.

Comment: Хорошо, если моя догадка неверна, то скажи мне пожалуйста почему у него не работает @media (max-width: 767px)?

Comment: Вот если бы он пример привёл, то можно было бы сказать...